# How to generate IPA for a developer role in Apple developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, provisioning-profile, ipa

My personal developer account has been added as developer role to an paid developer account. Now I'm trying to build ipa by using my personal developer team account, but I'm facing an error. Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Do I have to disable automatically manage signing? And export the provision file manually or how should I approach on this

[Error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wXBy.jpg)

Comment: You must to create a provisioning profile, download the certificate and install in you PC .

Answer (score 1):

You need two things to make a build using Xcode. Provisioning profile & a matching signing certificate.

### **Signing Certificate**

Your admin role will generate this signing certificate which will contain the team ID. The certificate needs to be added to your keychain, Only then you will be able to use the provisioning profile attached to it.

### **Provisioning Profile**

This you will get from the admin role of that project. The admin has to generate a signing certificate. Then he has to use that certificate while generating a provisioning profile.

You're going to need three types of provisioning profile.

1. Development - To develop and debug.
2. Ad-hoc - You will have to add the [Device UDID](https://udid.tech/) of the devices you're going to add the IPA to.
3. App store - This you need to add your app to testflight and appstore eventually.

###### Note: You have to take support from the admin user of the apple developer account.

Comment: Do we need to add ourselves as developer too in admin apple account, in order to generate ipa?

Comment: No you do not need to add yourself as developer to generate IPA. However if you want to push your build to TestFlight then you need to add yourself as developer.

Comment: Do we need apple developement certificate and apple distribution certificate too from admin too? As i have to create build for client that he can upload to testflight or app store.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77417140/this-app-cannot-be-installed-because-its-integrity-could-not-be-verified

Can you guide me here.